# Restore Samsung Galaxy S II via PC

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-2, twrp, unbricking

Sadly during a bad **TWRP update** my **Samsung Galaxy S II** was bricked.

The TWRP comes from a SlimSaber rom with a custom kernel.

What i can actually do is put it in download mode, so via a PC it should be reflashed.

> **What are the steps to reflash the original or a compatible ROM?**

Answer (score 1):

In short try booting into recovery, by pressing and holding home, power and volume down. Wipe user data. Then use Odin to reflash. The OEM firmware can be downloaded from Samsung.

Follow the guide on this link. https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-recover-a-bricked-samsung-galaxy-s2/